# svn copy .... svn: No repository found in

Tags: svn, copy

I have a single svn repository containing multiple projects. Now I am trying to copy one project to the tags folder as part of a debugging thing I am doing - and I need to do this using the command line in windows 7.

First I haved checked out the project on my local machine:

```
   svn co svn+ssh://myhost/usr/local/repo/sample/trunk
```

Then I cd to the location and run svn ls:

```
E:\tmp\trunk>svn ls
pom.xml
sample-sub/
src/
E:\tmp\trunk>
```

Next I try to copy the project (content of trunk) to the tags folder (the remote folder 'tags' already exists):

```
E:\tmp\trunk>svn copy svn://myhost/usr/local/repo/sample/trunk svn://myhost/usr/local/repo/sample/tags/sample-1.0.0
svn: No repository found in 'svn://myhost/usr/local/repo/sample'

E:\tmp\trunk>svn ls
```

but I get the above error. If I run svn info I get:

```
E:\tmp\trunk>svn info
Path: .
URL: svn+ssh://myhost/usr/local/repo/sample/trunk
Repository Root: svn+ssh://myhost/usr/local/repo/
Repository UUID: 4f716d61-fec0-4aa6-a1f0-23588c1997b0
Revision: 6426
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
```

why do I get the error:

```
svn: No repository found in 'svn://myhost/usr/local/repo/sample'
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different protocol schema `svn+ssh:` and just `svn:`.